# Invalid HTML when testing with XPather

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I would like to use [xpather](http://xpather.com/) to test out some XPATH on a [webpage](https://www.rawstory.com/). I am using chrome to "View source" on the webpage and then copying the source html into the left window on xpather. However xpather indicates that from an XML point of view the HTML is invalid. I get 2 main types of errors:

> The id value must be unique.
>
> Tag must be paired, no start tag

I definitely want to test out XPATH expressions directly on the HTML source as this frees me to focus on the XPATH query itself. It also allows me to validate results that I am getting through third-party libraries such as `lxml` in python. Just fyi, `lxml` does not seem to have a problem with the html and can turn it to an `etree` element with no issues.

What should I do here? I can think of two possibilities:

- validate the HTML first to ensure it is accepted by xpather. However I'm not sure if its possible to do that without actually modifying the original html. I would like to keep the webpage source intact if possible.
- Find another tool with can run XPATH expressions directly on html. Is there such a thing as "HPATH"?

Comment: XML and HTML are two different types and analyzing HTML *from an XML point of view* doesn't make much sense. YES `@id` should be unique (if possible ask developer to fix the issue) but NO in HTML tag must NOT be paired (elements like `input`, `br` has no closing tag, some tags might be self-closed with no starting tag). Also there is no such thing as HPATH as XPath deals fine with HTML. If you have some specific issue feel free to post it. Also please use [XPath tester](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) compatible with HTML

Comment: I have already tried XPath tester but it also gives me xml validation errors. I found that there are extensions to chrome which will evaluate and highlight the results of XPath statements on the webpage. That's nice but is there also a tool which will highlight the result on the html source code itself similar to Xpather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing an xpath directly on a web page with Chrome, open Chrome Developer Tools and execute `$x(xpath)` in Console. For example:

```
$x('//div[@id="col-center"]/div[2]/h1/a')
```

Developer Tools also allows you to inspect an element on the page (right click -> Inspect) and copy the xpath (right click -> Copy xpath).

Comment: I agree this might be the best way to do it. It doesn't require any 3rd party extensions and uses the native google chrome console directly. It's not as nice as Xpather but oh well... Just need to get more familiar with JavaScript I guess